# Dialer app doesn't show dial button

Tags: cyanogenmod, chrome-for-android, phone-app

When I tap a number in Chrome Mobile my default Dialer app opens and shows the below screen. I struggle finding out how to actually dial the number, there is no button for that at all. I've been scratching my header of this for a while now. Is it a user interface bug? Or is it me?

I'm running Android 5.1.1 + Cyanogen OS 12.1 using the Mono Tropicalgreen theme on a Oneplus One.

**Screen1:**

I can either create a new contact or send an SMS, but there is no 'dial' button. Pressing the back button brings me back to Chrome.

[image: screenshot]

**Screen2:**

The options panel doesn't give me a 'dial' action either.

[image: screenshot]

**Screen3:**

The other panel doesn't give me a 'dial' either.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It's aa problem of Theme,Change the Theme